# List of files as input argument for a bash script

Tags: bash, list, cluster-computing

I have a list of files:

```
path/dir/*.gz
```

And I want to give this list of files as input in my bash script, together with other arguments related to the analyses (i.e. output folder and number of threads).

```
./myscript.sh path/dir/*.gz output_path 2
```

The myscript.sh includes the following command:

```
fastqc $1 -o $2 -t $3 --noextract -d ./
```

The fastqc program is able to run on several threads the list of input files.
I'm using this script in a SGE cluster, therefore using the command "qsub".
And I ran it in the following way:

```
qsub ./myscript.sh path/dir/*.gz output_path 2
```

However, it does not work. Someone knows why and can suggest a solution?
My understanding is that I'm messing up with the list of input files as argument.

Comment: I do not really know, it is not specified in the manual. But If I run it as     fastqc path/dir/*.gz output_path 2    , it works fine.

Comment: Try to run it as: `./myscript.sh 'path/dir/*.gz' output_path 2`

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the wildcard is expanding to individual filenames by the shell *before* your script is launched.

Here are a couple of strategies:

1. pick out the last 2 arguments from the list:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   if (( $# < 3 )); then
       echo not enough arguments
       exit 1
   fi

   # threads is the last argument
   n=$#
   threads=${!n}

   # output_path is the 2nd-last argument
   ((n--))
   output_path=${!n}

   # discard the last 2 arguments
   ((n--))
   set -- "${@:1:n}"

   # now "$@" is the list of input files.
   for file in "$@"; do
       fastqc "$file" -o "$output_path" -t "$threads" --noextract -d ./
   done
   ```

   This uses "indirect variables" (`${!n}`) to extract the value of the positional parameter for the number $n.
2. use command line options to provide the output path and number of threads:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while getopts :o:t:h opt; do
       case $opt in
           h) show_help; exit ;;
           o) output_path=$OPTARG ;;
           t) threads=$OPTARG ;;
           *) exit ;; # some error
       esac
   done

   if [[ -z $output_path ]]; then
       echo error message
       exit 1
   fi
   if [[ -z $threads ]]; then 
       echo error message
       exit 1
   fi
   # other validations, like $threads is a sensible whole number

   shift $((OPTIND - 1))

   # now "$@" is the list of input files.
   for file in "$@"; do
       fastqc "$file" -o "$output_path" -t "$threads" --noextract -d ./
   done
   ```

---

I don't know `fastqc` but if it can take multiple input files, then instead of the loop, do

```
fastqc "$@" -o "$output_path" -t "$threads" --noextract -d ./
```

Comment: Another option (the one I'd prefer) is to put the output file and thread count first in the arg list (`$1` and `$3`), with the input files being the rest of the arguments (`$3` through `$whatever`, which bash conveniently lets you retrieve as `${@:3}`). Then you can just do `fastqc "${@:3}" -o "$1" -t "$2" --noextract -d ./` in the script.